# "TypeError: data[option] is undefined" en un dropdown de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, dropdownlist, dropdown

a ver si por aquí alguien puede proporcionarme una ayuda con esto...
Tengo un select list que está hecho así:

```
<div class="simple-selector dropdown w-100">
    <button class="selector form-control" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="selected-text" name="my-selected" data-value="">
                         Selecciona un elemento...
                    </span>
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-down small"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu selector-menu w-100 overflow-scroll" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li class="dropdown-item p-small css-bg-gris-9-hover" data-item="item-uno">
            <span class="li-text">
                <img class="dropdown-item-img item-in-list" style="width: 25px;" id="item-uno_icon" src="logo-item-uno.png" alt="item-uno"> Este es el Item 1
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item p-small css-bg-gris-9-hover" data-in-list="item-dos">
            <span class="li-text">
                <img class="dropdown-item-img item-in-list" style="width: 25px;" id="item-dos_icon" src="logo-item-dos.png" alt="item-dos"> Este es el Item 2
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item p-small css-bg-gris-9-hover" data-in-list="item-tres">
            <span class="li-text">
                <img class="dropdown-item-img item-in-list" style="width: 25px;" id="item-tres_icon" src="logo-item-tres.png" alt="item-tres"> Este es el Item 3
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Pues bien, para gestionar los eventos de este select uso el siguiente `javascript`:

```
//detectando si tiene un dropdown dentro de otro
var dropdownInsideAnother = false;
$('.simple-selector .selector-menu li [data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]').on('mousedown', function () {
    let dropdownId = $(this).attr('id');
    dropdownInsideAnother = true;
    $('#' + dropdownId).on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
        dropdownInsideAnother = false;
    })
})
//función que añade la selección
$('.simple-selector .selector-menu li').on('mouseup', function () {
    var mainParent = $(this).parents('.simple-selector'),
        content = $('.li-text', this).text(),
        dropdownId = mainParent.find('.selector-menu').attr('aria-labelledby');
    if (!dropdownInsideAnother) {
        let imgurl = $('.dropdown-item-img', this).attr('src');
        if (imgurl !== 'undefined' || imgurl !== '') {
            var img = '<img style="width:25px;" class="dropdown-item-img" src="' + imgurl + '" />' + content;
            mainParent.find('.selector .selected-text').html(img)
        } else {
            mainParent.find('.selector .selected-text').text(content);
        }
        $('#' + dropdownId).dropdown('hide');
    }
})
```

Este código es genérico y es utilizado en diversas partes de la aplicación. Parece que funciona bien o al menos hace lo que se supone que debería hacer, pero cada vez que lo uso, en cosola aparece un error que viene de `Bootstrap: dropdown.js v3.4.1` en la sigiente función:

```
function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }
```

El error devuelto es `TypeError: data[option] is undefined` y por lo que he averiguado es porque `data = new Dropdown(this)` carga la variable `data` con un *undefined*.

Para más información, al poner puntos de interrupción he visto que cuando da el error, `option` es igual a "*hide*".

Espero que alguien poueda ayudarme con esto.

P.D.: Estoy usando Firefox.

Incluyo un snippet del código en el cual utilizo la misma versión de Bootstrap:

```js
//detectando si tiene un dropdown dentro de otro
    var dropdownInsideAnother = false;
    $('.simple-selector .selector-menu li [data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]').on('mousedown', function () {
        let dropdownId = $(this).attr('id');
        dropdownInsideAnother = true;
        $('#' + dropdownId).on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
            dropdownInsideAnother = false;
        })
    })
    //función que añade la selección
    $('.simple-selector .selector-menu li').on('mouseup', function () {
        var mainParent = $(this).parents('.simple-selector'),
            content = $('.li-text', this).text(),
            dropdownId = mainParent.find('.selector-menu').attr('aria-labelledby');
        if (!dropdownInsideAnother) {
            let imgurl = $('.dropdown-item-img', this).attr('src');
            if (imgurl !== 'undefined' || imgurl !== '') {
                var img = '<img style="width:25px;" class="dropdown-item-img" src="' + imgurl + '" />' + content;
                mainParent.find('.selector .selected-text').html(img)
            } else {
                mainParent.find('.selector .selected-text').text(content);
            }
            $('#' + dropdownId).dropdown('hide');
        }
    })
    
    function Plugin(option) {
        return this.each(function () {
          var $this = $(this)
          var data  = $this.data('bs.dropdown')
    
          if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
          if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
        })
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="simple-selector dropdown w-100">
        <button class="selector form-control" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="selected-text" name="my-selected" data-value="">
                             Selecciona un elemento...
                        </span>
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-down small"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu selector-menu w-100 overflow-scroll" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <li class="dropdown-item p-small css-bg-gris-9-hover" data-item="item-uno">
                <span class="li-text">
                    <img class="dropdown-item-img item-in-list" style="width: 25px;" id="item-uno_icon" src="logo-item-uno.png" alt="item-uno"> Este es el Item 1
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item p-small css-bg-gris-9-hover" data-in-list="item-dos">
                <span class="li-text">
                    <img class="dropdown-item-img item-in-list" style="width: 25px;" id="item-dos_icon" src="logo-item-dos.png" alt="item-dos"> Este es el Item 2
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item p-small css-bg-gris-9-hover" data-in-list="item-tres">
                <span class="li-text">
                    <img class="dropdown-item-img item-in-list" style="width: 25px;" id="item-tres_icon" src="logo-item-tres.png" alt="item-tres"> Este es el Item 3
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mencionar en la pregunta qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando? Incluso, podrías agregar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma, incluyendo además las librerías que estás utilizando con su correspondiente versión.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por el comentario @padaleiana! Ya está añadido el snippet.